# New artifact referencing an existing - Governance Issue

Tags: dependencies, wso2, governance-registry, soa-governance, wso2-governance-registry

[image]

I’m uploading new artifacts in Greg trying to referrer an existing. For example, I have A.xsd, B.xsd and C.xsd on Greg , and I’m uploading a WSDL referring them but it doesn’t work.  A have other scenarios with xsd, wadl and other artifacts. 
Is it a bug ? If yes this is serious because it is a Governance tool.
I have used these references:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance501/Uploading+Schemas+with+Imports+from+Local+Filesystem+into+Governance+Registry
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance501/Creating+a+Governance+Archive

Comment: What is the G-Reg version your using ??

Answer (score 2):

**No, As far as I understand this is not a bug**. You can't refer something already uploaded to the registry from WSDL file that you are going to upload. Therefore please include A.xsd, B.xsd and C.xsd schema files with WSDL and upload the complete folder as a zip file. For that you can use wsdl zip file uplad form. If you uploading A.xsd, B.xsd, and C.xsd multiple times G-Reg will look after the overriding part for you.

@LeandroGoncalves Could create a zip file which contains basics.xsd, tiposBasico.xsd, xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, and leiauteNFe.xsd in the root and try to upload that zip file using schema file upload wizard in publisher. this issue will not happen.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Let me try to be more specific.

Comment: I uploaded two basics xsd, tiposBasico.xsd and xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, its works ! But when I tred to upload a new xsd (leiauteNFe) in which depends on these two it doesn't work. Plese see the xsd structure :

Comment: `code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.10">
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
 <xs:include schemaLocation="tiposBasico.xsd"/>
   `code`

Comment: @LeandroGoncalves Could create a zip file which contains basics.xsd, tiposBasico.xsd, xmldsig-core-schema.xsd, and leiauteNFe.xsd in the root and try to upload that zip file using schema file upload wizard in publisher. this issue will not happen. Please check and let me know.

Comment: @LeandroGoncalves Please feel free to accept or comment on the answer to encourage the answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However it isn't usefull, if the G-REG users always upload an artifact with all dependecies, G-REG are not doing a correct job, I mean, when we look for a schema dependencies the correct is all show all depencies without duplications. In the real world,  we have many complex shemas having dependencies with basics schemas and all of them having distinct lifecycles.

Comment: My answer is a statement that tries to answer your question. If it is not , fine at least I tried. I do it for pleasure and I'm not getting paid for this. Stack overflow not a place to raise your development support issues. For that please contact WSO2. It is really disappointing to see this type of comments.